# Why, for an integer $s$ and a prime $p$, does $\gcd((s^p-1)/(s-1), s-1)$ divide $p$?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $a,b$ be two positive integers, and let $\gcd(a,b)$ denote the greatest common divisor for $a$ and $b$. Let $s>1$ be an integer and $p$ a prime number; then
\begin{equation}
\gcd\left(\frac{s^p-1}{s-1},s-1\right)
\end{equation}
divides $p$. Why?

Answer (score 5):

Let $d|s-1$ so that $s \equiv 1 \mod d.$ Then $(s^p-1)/(s-1) = 1+s+\dots+s^{p-1} \equiv p \mod d,$ so in order for $d$ to also divide $(s^p-1)/(s-1)$ we must have $d|p.$